# Can migrations be used to create dynamic table names?

Tags: migration, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I want to create a new table for each user. For example, when a user signs up, a table should be created having name `'User-uniqueID'`. Can this be achieved through migrations? Or else should I use a [stored procedure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stored_procedure) for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes I usually use this method for dinamic table creation see below (in this case i create a table  for user region/land_scope_code:

```
class m150420_221138_test extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {


        $tableOptions = 'CHARACTER SET utf8 ENGINE=InnoDB';

        $modelUserParam = UserParam::findOne(['user_id'=> Yii::$app->user->id]);


        $tableName = '_yourTableName';

        $this->createTable( $modelUserParam->land_scope_code . $tableName, [
            yourfield,
                ....... 
            'id' =>  'pk', 
        ], $tableOptions);

    }

    public function down()
    {

        $modelUserParam = UserParam::findOne(['user_id'=> Yii::$app->user->id]);


        $tableName = '_yourTableName';

        $this->droptable(  $modelUserParam->land_scope_code. $tableName);
    }

    /*
    // Use safeUp/safeDown to run migration code within a transaction
    public function safeUp()
    {
    }

    public function safeDown()
    {
    }
    */
}
```

Comment: Great! I will give it a try. One question though how do you run this migration? Using console runner extension?

Comment: No in this case I have adapted a my web module for use also with server where i don't can access to console.